# nvidia drivers on backtrack 5 gnome 32 bit (X session failed to start)

Tags: nvidia, gnome, drivers, xorg, backtrack-linux

i've got 2 graphic cards on my laptop : 1- intel integrated HD 3000   2-Nvidia GT540m

just disabled nouveau drivers and installed nvidia drivers (official drivers from nvidia.com)

now when trying to start X, i get the error msg:

> X failed to start, no screens found ...

i can get my desktop back by removing xorg.conf file, but i want nvidia drivers Loaded ...

## here's my xorg.0.log file :

```
X.Org X Server 1.7.6
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux bt 3.2.6 #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 10:40:05 EST 2012 i686
Build Date: 25 February 2012  06:59:39AM
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 12 05:01:51 2013
(==) Using config directory: "/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
(**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
(==) Automatically enabling devices
    Entry deleted from font path.
    Entry deleted from font path.
    Entry deleted from font path.
    Entry deleted from font path.
    Entry deleted from font path.
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
(==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
(WW) Disabling Keyboard0
(II) Loader magic: 0x81f0e80
    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    X.Org XInput driver : 7.0
(--) using VT number 7
(--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0116:1462:108d Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
(II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) LoadModule: "dbe"
(II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  310.44  Wed Mar 27 15:19:40 PDT 2013
(II) LoadModule: "record"
(II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.1.0
(II) Loading extension DRI2
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
(II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  310.44  Wed Mar 27 15:01:27 PDT 2013
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 00@00:02:0

no screens found
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 for help.
```

## and /etc/default/grub file :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text video=i915:modeset=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 pcie_aspm=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

just hope this helps finding the solution...

Answer (score 0):

use this command:`mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`

Comment: dude i mentioned : i can get my desktop back by removing xorg.conf file, but i want nvidia drivers Loaded ...

Answer (score 0):

i've just found the solution, should install bumblebee, virtualgl, linux-headers and mesa-utils . so here's what i did to get it working:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable # bumblebee ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-`uname -r` mesa-utils # update apt and install them
sudo su -c "useradd -G bumblebee USERNAME" # add the user to bumblebee group.
```

here's the link where i found the solution: 
[nvidia optimus bumblebee](http://www.linux.org/threads/nvidia-optimus-on-linux.4415/)

hope this could help someone else too...